# Why to assign an object attribute values cannot be read after？

Tags: javascript

```
var a = 1;
a.a = 2;
console.log(a.a);
```

In the last ,why the input is undefined, but not 2

Comment: Numbers don't have properties.

Comment: but `new Number` do :p

Answer (score 2):

At the moment you assigns the number 1 to the variable a (`var a = 1;`), a is a number. Altough Javascript doesn't specifically have types, the system from that point of time on treats the variable a as a number. So you can't add a property to a because it's not an object.

Here a little example of objects and variables:

```js
var a = 1;
console.log(typeof a); //prints number

a.a = 2;
console.log(typeof a); //still a number

var a = {} //redeclare a as an object
a.a = 2; //an object can have properties (a.a)
console.log(typeof a); //prints object
console.log(a.a); //prints 2
```